# regex for custom folder path

Tags: php, html, regex

I need a custom regular expression for folder paths as follows:

MEAL/JSH-2016/I-39

MEAL/HGIK-2021/IJDE/I-39

MECSL/GK-2011/IS-DE-393/I-39

Alphanumeric with(out) hyphen / Alphanumeric with(out) hyphen / Alphanumeric with(out) hyphen

I require the above kind of format, but it can have as many levels as possible. But it should not allow HTML tags.

I require this for a HTML form pattern check.

Can someone help me out? I can't seem to figure out the expression.

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: so, three "Alphanumeric with hyphen" sections is the minimum? I mean, would this string `bobby/JSH-2016` be a valid path in your case? Is the hyphen optional in a  very first part/section?

Comment: `Alphanumeric with hyphen / Alphanumeric with hyphen / Alphanumeric with hyphen` != `MEAL/JSH-2016/I-39`. I'll leave you with http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html and http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php.

Comment: Yes `bobby/JSH-2016` should be valid

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regular expression:

```
/^[a-z\d-]+(\/[a-z\d-]+)*$/i
```

Example use:

```
$path = "MECSL/GK-2011/IS-DE-393/I-39";
if (preg_match("/^[a-z\d-]+(\/[a-z\d-]+)*$/i", $path)) {
    echo "match!";
} else {
    echo "Not a valid path";
}
```

Note that this will not match paths that start or end with a slash, nor paths that contain two consecutive slashes.

Comment: Did this answer your question? Could you leave a comment?